# An explanation of how $(m+n)^2 -(m'+n')^2 = n'-n$ entails $|m+n+m'+n'|\cdot|m+n-m'-n'|=|n'-n|$

Tags: polynomials

I'm self-studying the Royden-Fitzpatrick book on Real Analysis, and just have a question about what I think should be an elementary step in the proof of Corollary 4 in chapter 1, which I don't seem to be able to fully work out on my own. It says that from $(m+n)^2 -(m'+n')^2 = n'-n$ we can infer $|m+n+m'+n'|\cdot|m+n-m'-n'|=|n'-n|$. I can sort of see how this follows but I must have missed the technique you would use to show this. I was wondering if anyone could break down the inference in detail? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ we get
$$(m+n)^2 -(m'+n')^2=(m+n+m'+n')(m+n-m'-n')$$
and so
$$|(m+n)^2 -(m'+n')^2|=|m+n+m'+n'||m+n-m'-n'|.$$
Then
$$(m+n)^2 -(m'+n')^2 = n'-n$$
implies
$$|(m+n)^2 -(m'+n')^2| = |n'-n|$$
which is equivalent to
$$|m+n+m'+n'||m+n-m'-n'|=|n'-n|.$$